# redirect a submit button to another page

Tags: php, html

I have a code that is based on a page to collect data and perform calculations, however I need a final button written submit to save the typed data and redirect to another page. Can anyone help me to save?

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
    
        print_r('Nome' . $_POST['nome']);
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $plantada = $_POST['plantada'];
        $ctc = $_POST['ctc'];
        $tabela = $_POST['tabela'];
        $vporcento = $_POST['vporcento'];
        $prnt = $_POST['prnt'];


    }


        <br>
        <a type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
        </div>
```

In my code I have a tag that is based on a button that ends the form step. I want this button to redirect to a new page... Is it possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An34T.png)

Comment: Look at `<form action="OTHER-PAGE" ...>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the $_SESSION variable to temporarily store your first submitted data. On the second page, create a submit form and check if the $_SESSION variable exists before proceeding.

Here is an example code:

firstpage.php:

```php
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['something'])) {
    $_SESSION['something'] = $_POST['something'];
    header('Location: secondpage.php');
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="something">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

secondpage.php:

```php
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['something'])) {
    die('You are not allowed to access this page');
}
?>

Your first page data is: <?php echo $_SESSION['something']; ?>
<form action="thirdpage.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

thirdpage.php:

```php
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['something'])) {
    die('You are not allowed to access this page');
}

echo 'Your first page data is: ' . $_SESSION['something'];
?>
```